# Android - Screenshot of homescreen with button

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, screenshot

I am trying to port a windows program I made called Desktop Concealer to android. This program works like any other logout program, but it doesnt actually logout. Which gives the user access to the computer which could be used for a list of things(downloads, installing programs).

The program takes a screenshot of the entire desktop before actually showing the form. Then it gives a login password option. when the user decides its time to logout. the program displays the screenshot over the entire desktop, when clicked anywhere it shows a logout window.

I want to know if i could take a picture / screenshot of the homescreen without having to be there, or if not possible; How could i take a screenshot.

here is a demo of the program on youtube to give you a better understanding of how it works:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Gl4hNXI7oo

Comment: Android is designed to prohibit unwise things like this.

Comment: This sounds like the most pointless program ever conceived...

Comment: I do not understand it properly, but it sounds like it is intended to be used for fishy stuff.

Comment: this is a program thats like a spoof program, Like screen crack. But This app actually has a purpose. when people goto the lockscreen it shows the homescreen picture. then when you touch anywhere it ask for your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if i could take a picture / screenshot of the homescreen without having to be there

In general, you cannot take a screenshot programmatically in any circumstances, for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: ok, could i leave the app. take the screenshot then return?

Comment: @MoschDev: What part of "you cannot take a screenshot programmatically in any circumstances, for security and privacy reasons" was unclear to you?